# How to pass touch events to android from unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a plugin for Android that using Android jar file to show an Android view above the Unity view.

That works fine but the problem is that Unity doesn't pass the touch events to my view.

How can I pass the touch events to my view from Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer:

```
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
```

Needed to be changed to

```
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
```

in the manifest

Comment: I assume this means that dispatchKeyEvent should be called on UnityPlayerNativeActivity whenever the keyboard is used. But it's not. I had to switch to UnityPlayerActivity completely instead. Any ideas?

Comment: onTouchEvent method get called using this.